# WSO2 ESB and WSO2 Data Services Server not running as Windows Services simultaneously on the same server

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have installed **WSO2 DSS 3.5.0** and **WSO2 ESB 4.9.0** on the same server as windows services with the ESB port `offset = 1` in the `carbon.xml` file.

Both services when started separately are running fine but when I try to run both simultaneously then either DSS runs or ESB runs and the other service fails to start.

Seems like a port conflict somewhere but I am unable to find any relevant logs. Please help to resolve this issue.
[Log Files and Wrapper and Carbon Conf files attached](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xrjdpy3g968lmln/Logs.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Can you attach the logs? There shouldn't any such issue as we noticed.

Comment: Logs have been attached. its a Virtual Server running VMWare with OS=Windows 2008 Server R2 Standard with SP1

Comment: log file is in <CARBON_HOME>/repository/logs folder. can you attach wso2carbon.log from that folder for both servers?

Comment: Since the ESB Windows service fails to start if the DSS Windows service is running, no log is created under <CARBON_HOME>/repository/logs folder

Comment: do you get any error code when it fails to start?

Comment: Log from DSS service which runs fine is attached : [https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ovs14tkuwizgck/wso2carbon.log?dl=0]

Comment: Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Comment: it returns 404 for logs in DSS service you attached.

Comment: DSS Service is running fine, ESB service fails to start with windows service error code 1053. System event logs attached previously. If i stop DSS windows service and then start ESB service, it works fine but then DSS service fails to start with the same error code 1053.

Comment: Did you try out https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/839174

Comment: The support article is not applicable in my environment since i am running .NET framework 4. Currently DSS is running as windows service and ESB is running through wso2server.bat file without any issues but i need to run ESB also as windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the blog post below[1] to overcome this issue. The blog explains how two services can be run as windows services.

Some important areas to consider when setting up two nodes as windows services are :
1.create two folders as 'esb_service' and 'dss_service'

2.As shown on[1] please update the esb_home and dss_home on the relevant places within the wrapper conf replacing the carbon_home

3.Make sure that the port offset of one of the two nodes is incremented by one to avoid port conflict.

4.start the two yajsw-stable-11.03 with installService.bat and startService.bat to get the services running

Note: I have tried this scenario using yajsw-stable-11.03 version.

[1]http://blog.lasindu.com/2015/05/how-to-start-two-or-more-wso2-servers.html

regards,shavantha